# Actionbarsherlock: Menu buttons work in Froyo but not ICS?

Tags: android, button, actionbarsherlock

I have made an app [OB Nyt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bengaard.obnyt) that works well on Froyo and below - but on ICS and above nothing happens when I click the menu buttons (the link to update, the link to images activity and the link to search activity). When I click a button in ICS the buttons on my phone light - but the activities don't open as they do on Froyo. I have modified ActionBarSherlock very little. I know from a toast message that the click is registered in ICS. But the activity does not start. In the LogCat I get a

```
window already focused ignoring focus gain of com.android.internal.view.iinputmethodclient
```

every time I click one of the buttons. I have a guess that maybe it's around here that the problem might be:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = true;


    menu.add("Save")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_stilling1 : R.drawable.ic_stilling1)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Opdatér")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_refresh_inverse : R.drawable.ic_refresh)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //This uses the imported MenuItem from ActionBarSherlock
    Toast.makeText(this, "Got click: " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (item.toString()=="Save"){

        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), F3Activity.class));

        return true;
    }

    if (item.toString()=="Search"){

        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class));

        return true;
    }

    if (item.toString()=="Opdatér"){

        startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ABSTabsViewPagerActivity.class));

        return true;
    }



    return true;
}
```

As you can see I'm a noob in programming :-) Does anyone have a clue on how I can get the buttons to react in ICS? I've tested on Jelly Bean on my own old HTC Desire and ICS on my friends' Samsung Galaxy II and III with the exact same result.

[EDIT] : This made it work:

```
if (item.getTitle()=="Save")
```

instead of

```
if (item.toString()=="Save")
```

A beginner's mistake, I knew it ;-)

Comment: 99.9% of things in ActionBarSherlock work on every platform from 2.x up. The menu is not in the .1%

Comment: Could I start these activities in another way if I want to make sure that they open in ICS/ABS?

Comment: I would also return super.onXYZ instead of true both of those methods -- specifically if one of your conditions is not met in the second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.equals(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for string comparisons. The right approach would be

```
if ("Save".equals(item.getTitle()))
```

Consider giving your menu items an ID, and using that for figuring out which is clicked instead.

Answer (score -2):

This made it work:

```
if (item.getTitle()=="Save")
```

instead of

```
if (item.toString()=="Save")
```